# Multiple JButtons to perform the same task

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton

How to program multiple `JButton` objects to perform the same task?

I'm programming a game that uses 25 buttons on a game board. Each button does the exact same thing by generating a random number and changing the icon depending on the number.

Here is my code:

```
    Random RG1 = new Random();
    level_1_random_block = (RG1.nextInt(6));

    final JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("");
    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            frame2.setVisible(false);
            if (level_1_random_block == 0){
                btnNewButton.setIcon(new        ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreDiamond.png"));
                score += 100;
                initialize_score();
            }
            if (level_1_random_block == 1){
                btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreGold.png"));
                score += 25;
                initialize_score();
            }
            if (level_1_random_block == 2){
                btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreGold.png"));
                score += 25;
                initialize_score();
            }
            if (level_1_random_block == 3){
                btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreIron.png"));
                score += 5;
                initialize_score();
            }
            if (level_1_random_block == 4){
                btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreIron.png"));
                score += 5;
                initialize_score();
            }
            if (level_1_random_block == 5){
                btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\creeper.png"));
                score -= 30;
                initialize_score();
            }
            if (level_1_random_block == 6){
                btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\creeper.png"));
                score -= 30;
                initialize_score();
            }

            btnNewButton.removeMouseListener(this);
            level_1_move_on = true;
            continue_game();

        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\grass_side.png"));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 0, 87, 87);
    frame1.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
```

Everything works fine, but I'd like to know if there is an easier way of programming all the buttons to do this without writing 150 different `if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add mouse listeners. Just implement ActionListener in your class:

```
public SomeClass implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

And then attach `ActionListener` to your buttons:

```
btn.addActionListener(this);
```

Or as I mentioned with separated class:

```
public EventHandler implements ActionListener {
    int level_1_random_block;

    public EventHandler(int level_1_random_block) {
        this.level_1_random_block = level_1_random_block;    
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
        if (level_1_random_block == 0){
                    source.setIcon(new        ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreDiamond.png"));
                    score += 100;
                    initialize_score();
                }
                if (level_1_random_block == 1){
                    source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreGold.png"));
                    score += 25;
                    initialize_score();
                }
                if (level_1_random_block == 2){
                    source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreGold.png"));
                    score += 25;
                    initialize_score();
                }
                if (level_1_random_block == 3){
                    source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreIron.png"));
                    score += 5;
                    initialize_score();
                }
                if (level_1_random_block == 4){
                    source.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreIron.png"));
                    score += 5;
                    initialize_score();
                }

    }

}
```

To add this listener on your button:

```
btn.addActionListener(new EventHandler(level_1_random_block));
```

Comment: The only problem I have is that the button needs to change its icon, but each `btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Liam\\Desktop\\BOMB GAME\\oreDiamond.png"));` is specific to the button it's changing. Can I still use this?

Comment: @Hoberfinkle Yes ! Use the `ActionEvent#getSource()` and a cast :)

Comment: Yes. You can create separated class which implements `ActionListener`. You could use for loop to add `ActionListener` on your buttons. But unfortunately, you will have to put that logic with `if` statements in separated class.

Comment: @Hoberfinkle I updated my answer. Not quite accurate, but it should help you how to do it.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 4):

Well create a `ActionListener` subclass by implementing it with overriding the `actionPerformed` method, and then create an instance of it,  add the same instance to every `jButton` objects of your use-case.

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // your action to be performed
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** `MouseListener` is a low-level AWT-event listener in Swing where `ActionListener`is higher label and preferable to use. However, It is even better to use [**java.swing.Action**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) which is itself an `action listener` that provides not only `action-event` handling, but also centralized handling of the state of action-event-firing components such as `tool bar buttons`, `menu items`, `common buttons`, and `text fields`.

check [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) tutorial for more details.

Comment: Just remove that part with `MouseListener` and I will give you +1 too. Don't be so stubborn. :)

Comment: @brano, Hi(yes) hi(yes) sir. sorry for being stubborn. :)

Comment: Now **that** is an up-votable answer.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Some tips :

- use a `switch` instead of multiple `if`
- use an `ActionListener` instead of `MouseListener`
- inside the listener, access to the clicked button with `ActionEvent#getSource()`
- create only one `ActionListener` and add it to all your buttons

Hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

If all that's changing depending on the random number are the image paths and the score value, why not put those into an array or something of the sort and access them by index?

Actually, in case you need different behaviour later on, you could write a class that encapsulates those fields (image and score for now) and use an array/vector of instances of this class. That way it would be easy to expand.

Answer (score 0):

Make new class which will contain metadata about your action:

```
class Action{
    String image;
    int score;
}
```

Define instances for all your actions and put them in some data structure, as array or list, and mark them with appropriate index.
Then you can reach them by the ID.